# Adding a class to post title considering the title length

Tags: title

I searched for "title length" in questions but results were all about setting max length and limiting and..

What I want to do is to create an if-statement, to determine if the post title has more than 68 characters or not and if it had, add `smaller` class to it.

I wrote the code like this:

```
<?php
    $permaLength = strlen(the_title());
?>
<h2 class="<?php if ($permaLength > 68) {echo 'smaller';} ?>">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
        <?php the_title(); ?>
    </a>
</h2>
```

but it seems that `the_title()` function is not returning the value and instead it's echoing out. Is there an alternative way to fetch the title length?

Comment: [Don’t use `strlen()`](http://wpengineer.com/2410/dont-use-strlen/), use `mb_strlen()` instead.

Comment: 'but it seems that' - it would take less than 5 minutes to find out for sure, by searching the Codex; http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`the_title()` echoes the result. Use `get_the_title()` to return the title.